# How can I use User Agent to detect request is Coming from desktop or mobile?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

Here Is My method where I am getting userdetails who logging my application.I want to check the request is coming from `desktop` or `mobile`,using User agent.How can I do this?

```
        public UserDetails Authenticate()
        {
            try
            {
                _logger.Info("authenticating...");
                var message = OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage;
                var request = (HttpRequestMessageProperty)message.Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name];
                string token = request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization];
                var base64decodedtoken = this.Base64Decode(token);
                UserBLL user = new UserBLL();
                var userdetails = user.GetUserDetails(base64decodedtoken, true);    
                if (userdetails.UserId > 0)
                {
                    _logger.Info("authentication successfull... for user id" + userdetails.UserId);   
                    int i = user.AuditUserLogin(userdetails.Email);

                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.Info("Unauthorised Access" + userdetails.Email);
                }
                return userdetails;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error("Error Occured in Authentication Service", ex);
                ErrorData errorData = new ErrorData("Error Occured ", ex.Message);
                throw new WebFaultException<ErrorData>(errorData, HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent#Mobile_Tablet_or_Desktop) for your answer.

Basically, the mobile/desktop detection by user-agent is not suggested, but if you have to get your work sorted in this way, you can also refer to [this link](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/)